# How to write a binary relation in extension?

Tags: relations, binary

I have an exam coming up soon and I cant find my notes on binary relations and have been unable to find anything on extending binary relations online. I would appreciate if someone could walk me through how to to this. I am not asking to do every question but one part would be nice so I can get a grasp on what I am doing. Thank you in advance.

> Suppose two binary relations $R$ and $S$ over $(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})$ have been defined as:
>
> $R=\{(2,1),(2,3),(3,2),(3,3),(4,1),(4,2)\}$
>
> $S=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,1)\}$
>
> Write out each of the following binary relations in extension:
>
> (a) $R;S$
>
> (b) $S;R$
>
> (c) $R\setminus S$
>
> (d) $S;S;S$
>
> (e) $R;(S)^{-1}$

Comment: Here's a [mathjax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you're more likely to get help if you write your question in it opposed to posting an image link.

Comment: What is your problem? Is it just to write it in extension or to compute the relational product and other operations. The relations $R$ and $S$ are already represented in extension... So, for example, for (c), $R \setminus S$, given that $(2,3)$ is the only common element, you get $$R \setminus S = \{(2,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,1),(4,2)\}.$$

Comment: Ok thank you. What do the symbols mean? As in what does "/" and ";" in binary relations.

Answer (score 1):

(a) $R;S=\{(x,z): \exists y, xRy\land ySz\}$

So $R;S=\{(2,2),(2,1),(3,3),(3,1),(4,2),(4,3)\}$

(b) $S;R=\{(1,1),(1,3),(2,2),(2,3)\}$

(c) alreary answered (it is the set difference).

(d) $S;S;S=\{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)\}$

(e) $S^{-1}=\{(2,1),(3,2),(1,3)\}$

So $R;(S)^{-1}=\{(2,3),(2,3),(3,2),(4,3),(4,1)\}$